# iOS Sprite Kit resize sprite based on screen resolution

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Can anyone explain why you can take a background image sized for an iPad retina and put it in a sprite kit app and it resizes fine for all screen resolutions.  But, if you take a proportionately sized image and put it on a sprite there doesn't seem to be a way to resize it the same way that the background does?
Thanks

Comment: can you be more specific, ie give an example with code and image names & sizes used? Tell us how you came to that observation. It may simply be the scene scale mode perhaps. Or not using \@2x files, or only \@2x files.

Comment: If you are talking about image asset naming conventions then this thread might shed some light on it http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=9022

Answer (score 0):

Yep. The method talked about in the Ray Wenderlich article is what I ended up using.

LearnCocosD, since you are the man when it comes to this stuff (love your site BTW): what still confuses me is why Obj C would resize the background view like in a normal iOS app but not build the same ability into sprites.
Still: Ray Wenderlich and LearnCocos2D remain great resources.  Smart people over there.
Thanks LearnCocos2D and sangony.